# What are the way programmers are using to deploy its node.js app in ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, deployment, ubuntu-12.04, production-environment

What is the recommended way to deploy Node.js on Ubuntu 12.04 in a production environment?

I saw [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js/) but I don't know if is well maintained or if it will and if is a source in witch one can trust.

I know that is easy install Node.js manually, but seem to me that install it using the Ubuntu packages manager will allow me safe some management time and will be more integrated with the way the underlying server is being currently management. So, what are your recommendations? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after read lot of posts and pages that talk about Node.js deployment-installation, I must said that Chris PPA is mentioned in tons of them as an official source. Beside one can see her PPA linked at the [Github Node.js wiki](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager).

So, seem to me that is trust enough to be used in production, what made it the choice if you want keep your system updated using standards Ubuntu tools.

Answer (score 0):

we are using [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) with the existing [node.js cookbook](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/nodejs)

Comment: Can you explain more your reply? And why you consider it a better option that the chris lea's PPA?

Comment: im sorry, im not that familiar with our chef-setup, im more into our codebase. just wanted to give you some info what we are doing, but you can read more here: http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/About+Opscode+Chef

Comment: Thanks. As far I can read, Chef is some kind of deployment platform to deploy software on the cloud. What I'm asking for is a simple method to deploy in a single server. Thanks anyway.